# Accessibility of an ordered accordion list with a non-list-item interactive divider block

Tags: html, accessibility, html-lists, semantic-markup, screen-readers

### Background

There is a list of frequently asked questions and answers in the form of an accordion UI element:

```html
<h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
<ol class="accordion">
  <li>
    <h2>
      <button type="button" aria-expanded="false" class="accordion-trigger"
        aria-controls="question-1-answer" id="question-1">
        <span class="accordion-title">What is HTML?</span>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="question-1-answer" role="region" aria-labelledby="question-1"
      class="accordion-panel" hidden>HyperText Markup Language</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>
      <button type="button" aria-expanded="false" class="accordion-trigger"
        aria-controls="question-2-answer" id="question-2">
        <span class="accordion-title">What is CSS?</span>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="question-2-answer" role="region" aria-labelledby="question-1"
      class="accordion-panel" hidden>Cascading Style Sheets</div>
  </li>

  <!-- list divider start -->
  <div class="accordion-divider" role="region" aria-labelledby="divider-heading">
    <h2 id="divider-heading">Contact us to find out more</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- list divider end -->

  <li>
    <h2>
      <button type="button" aria-expanded="false" class="accordion-trigger"
        aria-controls="question-3-answer" id="question-3">
        <span class="accordion-title">What is JS?</span>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="question-3-answer" role="region" aria-labelledby="question-3"
      class="accordion-panel" hidden>JavaScript</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Between elements 2 and 3, there is a divider block which contains **interactive content** not relative to the list context (one could imagine an advertisement between the list elements with a call-to-action button).

### Problems

1. Screen reader (tested on macOS's VoiceOver) announces the list as containing 4 items when there should be 3 items and a divider block.
2. Screen reader should announce the divider block as independent content from the list.

### Questions

- How to accessibly describe that divider block so that the screen reader announces it correctly?
- Maybe there is a better way to semantically and accessibly describe an ordered accordion list  with a divider block?

### What I have tried already?

I have tried several WAI-ARIA roles on the divider block (such as `region` and `separator`), but the screen reader always announces the divider block as a part of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have valid HTML.  It's hard enough getting semantically correct HTML to be accessible but when you have invalid HTML, it's next to impossible.

The [spec for lists](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element:concept-element-content-model) says the `<ol>` can **only** have `<li>` elements as direct children.  Having a `<div>` as child of an `<ol>` will confuse the browser and the screen reader.  You can't have a non-list thing in the middle of the list items.

If you really want something to look like there's a block in the middle of the list, I can think of <s>two</s> <s>three</s> four things to do:

1. Insert the block at the end (or beginning) of a list item so it visually looks like it's not part of the list but it really will be.  I think this would still be confusing for screen reader users because it'll be hard to find the block
2. Have the block either before or after the list in the DOM but use CSS to move it "inside" the list.  The block would really be "on top" (as in `z-index`) of the list and not really "inside" it.
3. I suppose a third alternative is to go back to the designers and ask why you want a block in the middle of a list.
4. And lastly, which should actually solve your problem, create a list with two items (or however many you need before the block) and then close the list and have your block.  **Then** create your third list item as a standalone listitem and point your first list to this "orphaned" list item via [`aria-owns`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-owns).

You create an orphaned list by setting `role="presentation"` on it but having the first list take ownership of the second list's items.

You need to re-add the `role="listitem"` back to the list item because the parent's `role="presentation"` made the list item a presentational element because `role="presentation"` is propagated down to the children.  See the spec for [`role="presentation"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#presentation), in particular:

> When an explicit...role of presentation is applied to an element...that has **required owned elements**, in addition to the element with the explicit role of presentation, **the user agent MUST apply an inherited role of presentation to any owned elements** that do not have an explicit role defined.

That is, setting `role="presentation"` on a list will apply `role="presentation"` to the listitems (owned elements) as well.

```
<ol aria-owns="orphan">
  <li>...What is HTML...</li>
  <li>...What is CSS...</li>
</ol>

<!-- block of stuff -->
Contact us
<!-- block of stuff -->

<ol role="presentation">
  <li role="listitem" id="orphan">...What is JS...</li>
</ol>
```

You will probably have to use CSS `counter()` and `counter-increment` if you want the orphaned list to continue with numbers from your first list.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the list and your block in the middle of it,
as already pointed out, you can't have independent content in the middle of the list that isn't actually part of it.
It follows that, in any case, you will need to stay with some bizarre things:

- One too many will be announced as the total number of items, unless you use aria-size / aria-posinset, but maintaining these two attributes correct can quickly be thedious at long term, without saying that you should avoid using ARIA if you can, and there you can easily avoid it by doing it in another way.
- There is no simple way to make the list skip an item in the counting, unless by using CSS counters, but CSS generated content isn't always announced by screen readers
- You may split the list in two separate lists, but in this case screen reader users won't know the total number of items, and you will again need to use some tricks to make the counting correct

In fact, HTML lists haven't been designed to be broken in the middle, and there is no way to say that two lists must be joined together.
Those who just want to display a list of items in multiple columns have the same problem.

So the best and by far would of course be to don't break the list.

Sadly, I imagine that marketters have more power to decide than people working for accessibility.

However, semantically speaking, I'm not sure that you really need an ordered list in your FAQ example.
Having each question in a heading provide sufficient navigation. Navigation by heading makes it very easy, it's simpler, and well known by screen reader users.
_To me, it looks that wrapping the whole thing in a list is superfluous, unless, of course, if the question numbers are actually important.